# Composer install issue on prod, no issues on local enviroment

Tags: php, npm, gulp, composer-php

Recently I unignored composer.lock along with package-lock.json (likely unrelated), and I changed our gulp deploy script to use composer install instead of composer update. Before pushing new code to prod servers I updated the lock files to the latest using composer update and npm update to make sure there was nothing weird in there from branch merges.

However the gulp deployment script hit various issues, the most problematic of which was: "Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

gulp-tasks/deploy.js in its current state:

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
var exec = require('./helpers/exec');
var runSequence  = require('run-sequence');

module.exports = function (gulp, plugins, settings) {
    return function (completed) {

        var jsBundle = [];
        // Set production / staging only bundling options
        settings.env === 'production' || settings.env === 'staging'
            ? jsBundle.push('js:bundle-production')
            : jsBundle.push('js:bundle-vendor', 'js:bundle-vue', 'js:bundle-core');

        if (!args.x) { // Exclude mode
            console.log('Fetching latest commits from remote repository..');
            exec('git fetch');

            try {
                console.log('Attempting to merge upstream branch into local..');
                exec('git merge'); // If up-stream set on branch, merge it into local branch
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (args.v) { // Checkout version tag
            console.log('Checking out release tag..');
            exec('git checkout tags/' + args.v);
        }

        if (args.s) { // Speed mode
            console.log('Building JS and SASS..');
            runSequence(
                'make:htaccess',
                'sass:compile',
                'js:bundle-login',
                jsBundle,
                'copy-public',
                'remove:config',
                completed
            );
        } else if (args.b) {
            runSequence(
                'make:htaccess',
                'remove:config',
                completed
            );
        } else {
            // Full deploy
            // Create array for additional tasks we can pipe things like bugsnag into (this can't be empty)
            var extraTasks = ['remove:config'];
            if (settings.env === settings.production) {
                extraTasks.push('bugsnag'); // Add Bugsnag source maps on production
            }

            console.log('Installing composer packages..');
            exec('composer install');
            console.log('Installing NPM packages & pruning old packages..');
            exec('npm prune');
            // If deploying to a version then we don't want any potential package or package.lock changes saved
            if (args.v) {
                exec('npm install --no-save');
            } else {
                exec('npm install');
            }
            runSequence(
                'make:htaccess',
                'sass:compile',
                'js:bundle-login',
                jsBundle,
                'copy-public',
                extraTasks,
                completed
            );
        }

        if (args.u) {
            console.log('Running unit tests..');
            try {
                exec('./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap tests/unit/bootstrap.php -c tests/unit/phpunit.xml tests/unit');
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        if (args.y) {
            try {
                console.log('Updating system packages..');
                exec('[ -n "$(which yum)" ]');
                exec('sudo yum -y update');
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('yum not found.');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://wpackagist.org"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://company/repo/iputils.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://company/repo/phpwhois.git"
        }
    ],

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"company\\Database\\": "database/src"}
    },

    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-pdo": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "adobe-marketing-cloud/marketing-cloud-php-sdk": "2.1.x",
        "atrapalo/majesticseo-php-api-connector": "0.9.*",
        "aveiv/open-exchange-rates-api": "1.1",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.*",
        "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "1.10",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag": "^3.0",
        "diggin/diggin-http-charset": "dev-master",
        "eloquent/enumeration": "5.*",
        "google/apiclient": "2.1.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.*",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy": "^0.4.3",
        "kunststube/rison": "0.92",
        "league/csv": "^9.0",
        "pelago/emogrifier": "@dev",
        "php-di/php-di": "6.0.x",
        "companyrepo/iputils": "dev-master",
        "companyrepo/phpwhois": "dev-4-stable",
        "ramsey/uuid": "2.8.*",
        "shazam/php-slack": "^0.1.0",
        "sameer-shelavale/php-countries-array": "*",
        "symfony/intl": "^3.1",
        "zendframework/zendframework1": "1.*",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "3.*",
        "zendframework/zend-http": "2.7.0",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer": "^1.0",
        "johnpbloch/wordpress-core": "4.9.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/advanced-text-widget": "2.0.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/drafts-of-post-revisions": "0.8.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/image-widget": "4.2.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/inline-google-spreadsheet-viewer": "0.10.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/posts-to-posts": "1.6.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/post-types-order": "1.8.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/simple-page-ordering": "2.2.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/wp-migrate-db": "0.*",
        "wpackagist-plugin/wp-cerber": "6.*",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "dev-master",
        "simshaun/recurr": "3.0.5",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "^0.9.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "6.*",
        "phploc/phploc": "*",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "*",
        "slevomat/coding-standard": "~4.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "wordpress-install-dir": "public/support/wp",
        "installer-paths": {
            "public/support/support-content/plugins/{$name}/": ["type:wordpress-plugin"]
        }
    }
}
```

Deploy command we run on production servers: `gulp deploy -v tagversionnumber`

Composer diagnose example from one of the prod servers:

```
Checking composer.json: WARNING
No license specified, it is recommended to do so. For closed-source software you may use "proprietary" as license.
require.aveiv/open-exchange-rates-api : exact version constraints (1.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.bshaffer/oauth2-server-php : exact version constraints (1.10) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.diggin/diggin-http-charset : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.pelago/emogrifier : unbound version constraints (@dev) should be avoided
require.companyrepo/iputils : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.sameer-shelavale/php-countries-array : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.zendframework/zend-http : exact version constraints (2.7.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.zircote/swagger-php : unbound version constraints (dev-master) should be avoided
require.simshaun/recurr : exact version constraints (3.0.5) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
require.robmorgan/phinx : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
require.fzaninotto/faker : unbound version constraints (*) should be avoided
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking github.com rate limit: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: WARNING
You are not running the latest stable version, run `composer self-update` to update (1.3.0 => 1.7.2)
```

Some servers are running composer 1.2.2

On the same prod server `composer install --dry-run`:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - zendframework/zendframework 3.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-soap ^2.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].
    - zendframework/zendframework 3.0.0 requires zendframework/zend-soap ^2.6 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-soap[2.7.0].
    - zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for zendframework/zendframework 3.0.0 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zendframework[3.0.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-imap.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-xml.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/40-apcu.ini
    - /etc/php-7.1.d/php.ini
```

Note ext-soap is not on our local environments either, but install works fine there. And composer update works fine on both prod and local

Comment: Probably not related, but on production you most likely want to use `composer install --no-dev`.

Comment: Thanks @Furgas I'll add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install and enable php-soap extension.

```
zendframework/zend-soap 2.7.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.
```

Comment: Before I install extensions because composer claims they're missing I'm wondering why this isn't an issue on dev environment where we also don't have this extension, and also why this doesn't affect composer update.

Comment: Thank you, after writing that comment I went and double checked some things. For some reason the person who deployed recently does have it installed but others don't, so there's something wrong with our dev environments. Thankfully we're just changing our environments over to docker this week anyway. I'll be sure to add this extension